# How to access one class variable from another class in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use self.var1(defined in ClassA) inside ClassB in the below code. As we know the o/p of the program will be:

**Inside ClassB: 1 2

3**

But when I call object1.methodA(), I am updating self.var1 value and I want that value(updated) when I am calling object2.methodB() after it. How to achieve it?
I mean I want to access the latest value of self.var1 from ClassB.

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def methodA(self):
        self.var1 = self.var1 + self.var2
        return self.var1

class ClassB(ClassA):  
    def __init__(self, class_a):  
        self.var1 = class_a.var1  
        self.var2 = class_a.var2  
    def methodB(self):  
        print "Inside ClassB:",self.var1,self.var2  

object1 = ClassA()  
object2 = ClassB(object1)  
sum = object1.methodA()  
object2.methodB()  
print sum
```

Comment: You've got the concepts on Inheritance all wrong. First of all it doesnt make sense to create `var1` and `var2` in both classA and classB once the latter inherits from the former (and consequently already has these properties); also, you are creating two different objects and hoping that one's attributes influences the other's, which also makes no sense. Take a look at docs on OO and inheritance first, then move on and try what you're attempting to do https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Yes later I understood it's weird. Thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ClassB.__init__()`, you're just taking a snapshot of the `var1` and `var2` attributes of the passed in `ClassA` instance. If you need to see updated values of those attributes, store the instance itself:

```
class ClassB(ClassA):  
    def __init__(self, class_a):  
        self.class_a = class_a
    def methodB(self):  
        print "Inside ClassB:",self.class_a.var1,self.class_a.var2
```